# How to setup apache and php to make mail() function work on local machine

Tags: php, apache, email

I am using php's mail() function to send an email from a php scrpit, however, this is not working. I believe the problem is with my php setup and the lack of an smtp server. Does anyone have experience with setting something like this up on a local machine and what can be done to fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have on Windows machine. You should install local mail server, for example ArGoSoft Mail Server (www.argosoft.com). It's free, small and simple. Then setup a local domain in settings (for example weblocal.dom), then add a mail user (for example admin). So your test email will be admin@weblocal.dom. Then you just add this mail account to your email client program and send some mail to it from PHP script.

Comment: i think this is what i went. however, is there a way to just forward emails received by this account without using outlook/thunderbird/etc.?

Comment: This free version of program doesn't have such option.